# Can I use associations when using Ruby on Rails w/Amazon SimpleDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-simpledb

For a new project my company is considering using Amazon SimpleDB to simplify data storage.  The app is a simplistic web dashboard that will be created using Ruby on Rails.  What I'm wondering, though, is if I can still use associations like `has_many` and `belongs_to` while using SimpleDB as the backend.

For instance, the application has users who log in and have messages.  In "normal" Rails with MySQL I could easily do this with the built-in associations.  Will using SimpleDB as the storage engine prevent me from doing this?  Also, will I have to re-implement the login functionality?  I was initially going to use the `restful_authentication` plugin, but I have no idea if I will have to rewrite it to work with SimpleDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SimpleDB will be a problem for your wishes....

(and i tink you have to reimplement the login authentication as well, because its based on ActiveRecord like all the other models)..

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [SimpleRecord](http://gemcutter.org/gems/simple_record), just like ActiveRecord, but using SimpleDB for backend.